# How to use output from openssl encryption routines in a pipe?

Tags: shell, pipe, openssl

openssl manual claims that `openssl enc` uses standard output by default.

But something is not right with the standard output when decrypting a file. Piping the output to any application such as grep, results in openssl error:

```
error writing output file
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Example please.

Comment: Works for me: `echo hello | openssl enc -des3 -salt -e -k abc | openssl enc -des3 -d -k abc`

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that the reading end of the pipe has closed and openssl can no longer write to the pipe.  This will happen, for example, if you pipe to a command that terminates quickly without reading all its input:

```
$ dd count=400 if=/dev/urandom | openssl enc | true
error writing output file
```

Normally, a simple grep that finds nothing will work:

```
$ dd count=400 if=/dev/urandom | openssl enc | grep notgoingtomatch
```

But if the grep matches then notices that the input file is a pile of binary junk it will stop reading and the pipe is broken:

```
$ dd count=400 if=/dev/urandom | openssl enc | grep a
error writing output file
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

(In this case you can use `grep -a` to avoid the error).

Also, if you pipe the grep output into a pager like *less*, then quit *less* before seeing all the results, this will break the pipe output from grep, and grep will die if it has more to write, causing the openssl pipe to break too.